# Unable to add row dynamically in loop inside table in Razor

Tags: razor

I want to display 3 `Cells` in a row and then create row `<tr>` dynamically for remaining cells. When I searched for this logic, I am getting same answer from multiple articles about using `modulo` and it seems working for evryone but I'm not getting desired output. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
<table>
    @for (var i = 0; i < deliveryProvider.DeliveryTagInfo.DeliveryProviderTagList.Count; i++)
    {
        var deliveryTag = deliveryProvider.DeliveryTagInfo.DeliveryProviderTagList[i];

        if ((i%3) == 0) //Create new row for 4th item 
        {
            @:<tr>
        }
        <td>
            <div class="input-element checkbox">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.DeliveryProviderList[j].DeliveryTagInfo.IsDeliveryTagSelectedList[i], new
                {
                    name = deliveryTag,
                    id = deliveryTag
                })
                <label for="@deliveryTag">
                    <span></span>@deliveryTag</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        if ((i%3) == 0)
        {
            @:</tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

```
Test1

ALCOHOL   SPILLABLE    COLD_BAG

HOT_BAG    HEAVY       SIZE

Test2

abc  pqr  xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the problem code is in your closing tag.

```
    if ((i%3) == 0)
    {
        @:</tr>
    }
```

On your first iteration, i%3 is == 0, so you put a closing tag on your first statement. Essentially you are only creating `<tr>` tags on every third one.

Here is an example of how you could remedy this:

```
var listCount = 11;
for (var i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
{
    if (i%3 == 0)
    {
        @:<tr>
    }

    //Add Checkboxes

    //Closing Tag
    if (((i+1) % 3 == 0 )|| i == listCount - 1)
    {
        @:</tr>     
    }
}
```

Closing tag Explained...

For the first condition of the closing tag:

```
(i+1) % 3 == 0 )
```

Since the item has been added, we check to see if it is the third one- by using i+1, we will know how many items 
are in the row and we can close it if it is.

For the second condition:

```
i == listCount - 1
```

We also need to account for if it is the last item. If the list only has 2 items for example, we still need to close the row.